# Using SVN Hooks I can stop checkins of particular files by ACL, how can I do this with git?

Tags: git, svn

If we want to limit access to some file (eg: configuration files or project files) then in svn a hook can be used on the server to stop people from checking in changes to that file unless they are authorized by the hook script.

This is useful for pom.xml or build.gradle files as well as other configuration files as needed.

How can I achieve the same thing with git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use a centralized remote repo, the reliable way to do this is to put a pre-receive hook on the remote, which can reject attempts to push to the remote if they contain commits that make unauthorized changes.

Of course, this doesn't actually stop people from wasting their own time by committing changes locally that are destined to be rejected when pushed.  So you might want to also have a pre-commit hook that each developer can install locally to perform the same check and catch mistakes earlier.

The documentation for hooks is here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks